# How to flip an EncodedImage Blackberry

Tags: java, image, blackberry, flip

Hy. I want to flip horizontal an image and I use this code:

```
public static EncodedImage flip (Bitmap png)
{
    int width = png.getWidth();
    int height = png.getHeight();
    Bitmap temp = new Bitmap(width,height);
    int[] argb = new int[ width * height ];
    int[] invertArgb = new int[ width * height ];
    png.getARGB( argb, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height );

    for ( int i = height - 1; i >= 0; --i ) {
        for ( int j = width - 1; j >= 0; --j ) {
            invertArgb[ ( width - j - 1 ) + ( width * i ) ] = argb[ j + ( width * i ) ];
        }
    }
    temp.setARGB( invertArgb, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height );

    PNGEncoder encoder = new PNGEncoder(temp, true);
    byte[] imageBytes = null;
    try {
        imageBytes = encoder.encode(true);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    EncodedImage fullImage = EncodedImage.createEncodedImage(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length);

    return fullImage;

}
```

Buut.. does anyone have an ideea how to flip directly `EncodedImage` without converting because it's taking a little bit long

P.S. PNGEncoder.java is here: http://www.mobiyana.com/code/blackberry/PNGEncoder.java

Answer (score 1):

A valid solution is to provide two versions of the images; one normal and one flipped. Of course you will have to take into consideration the amount of time it takes to load versus the amount of space your images will require. It's a design decision that should at least be considered if you are looking for faster load times.

Comment: I am limited by the space (only 5mb) I can not add to many pictures. Anyway thanks for your intervention.

Answer (score 0):

Graphics.drawTexturedPath() can do things for you I suppose. Take a look at this [javadoc](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.7.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Graphics.html#drawTexturedPath%28int%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D,%20byte%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20net.rim.device.api.system.Bitmap%29) from RIM

Comment: yes but I made a game, and first I need to load flipped pictures and draw them in game-play